# Running DXA Java without registering WebCapability

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, web8.5, dxa-1.7

Currently I am struggling with DXA Java and Experience Manager not working. SDL suggested to remove `WebCapability` from my Discovery Service `cd_storage_conf.xml` and run the update script to upgrade capabilities in database. Once I did, my website was no longer running. I also noticed the [Webservice Express Installer](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-5A13B9C9-CB06-4847-BD0C-05F7AC37335C) isn't registering any WebCapability as well.

So my question is: How does the correct setup in terms of WebCapability looks like? Do I need to register it at all? How is my website supposed to run without it?

I'm using

- DXA Java 1.7
- Tomcat 8.5.6
- Web 8.5

Comment: Without registering your capabilities you can't have your site working as your broker is accessed via discovery.svc through content.svc and your discovery service should have all the capabilities configured in cd_storage_conf and to be registered with registration-jar. Now your configuration would have less entry in cd_storage than the capabilities registered so when you ran your registration tool it miss registered few hence site may not work. To get it working,  pickup the right config update with your details and run the registration tool again. Do add the capabilities you have. Should help

Comment: All capabilities are registered except WebCapability. In the past i always had it configured in my Discovery service `cd_dynamic_conf.xml` but SDL suggested to remove it. My question is more or less: Is there another way to have WebCapability without configuring it in Discovery service?

Comment: At the moment no, support is right, move capabilities from dynamic_conf to discovery cd_storage_conf. Do you have atleast this in cd_storage - <Role Name="WebCapability />?